# Find first image in google and insert next to keyword

Tags: excel, vba, macos, image, google-chrome

Im trying to find a script that inserts the first image based on a keyword  i.e. A1 "Abelia chinensis Variegata" finds a picture of the plant and puts it in B1

I have found the script below

Although the keyword is column D the results in A thy are returning zeros against each search

So unable to check if this does what i need it to.

I feel I'm so close, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub imagedownload()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim imgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim imgElement As HTMLImg
    Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim n As Integer, I As Integer
    Dim Url As String, url2 As String
    Dim m, LastRow As Long
    Dim furl As String
    Sheets("one").Select
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 3 To LastRow
        Url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(I, 4) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("one").Select
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .navigate Url 'sWebSiteURL
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            'Do Until IE.document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
            Set imgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("IMG")
            n = 1
            For Each imgElement In imgElements
                On Error Resume Next
                If InStr(imgElement.src, sImageSearchString) Then
                    If imgElement.ParentNode.nodeName = "A" Then
                        Set aElement = imgElement.ParentNode
                        'Cells(n, 2).Value = imgElement.src
                        'Cells(n, 3).Value = aElement.href
                        If n = 2 Then
                            url2 = aElement.href 'imgElement.src
                            url3 = imgElement.src 'aElement.href
                            GoTo done:
                        End If
                        n = n + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
done:
            furl = InStrRev(url2, "&imgrefurl=", -1)
            furl = Mid(url2, 37, furl - 37)
            Sheets("two").Select
            'On Error Resume Next
            Cells(I, 1) = furl
            Set m = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(furl)
            With Cells(I, 1)
                t = .Top
                l = .Left
                w = .Width
                h = .Height
            End With
            With m
                .Top = t
                .Left = l
                .ShapeRange.Width = w
                .ShapeRange.Height = h
            End With
            Sheets("one").Select
            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

The hope was to return an image  even if wrong against each keyword in D

Answer (score 2):

I've hacked away at your code and got it to work. It really needs a full re-write to be honest.

Please note: I've removed the need for a second sheet for testing purposes, but it should be fairly simple for you to put that back in.

```
Public Sub imagedownload()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim imgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim imgElement As HTMLImg
    Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim n As Integer, I As Integer
    Dim Url As String, url2 As String
    Dim m, LastRow As Long
    Dim furl As String
    Sheets("one").Select
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 3 To LastRow
        sImageSearchString = Cells(I, 4)
        Url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & sImageSearchString & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("one").Select
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate Url 'sWebSiteURL
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            'Do Until IE.document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
            Set imgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("IMG")
            furl = ""
            For Each imgElement In imgElements
                On Error Resume Next
                If furl = "" And InStr(imgElement.src, "gstatic") Then
                    furl = imgElement.src
                End If
            Next

            Cells(I, 6) = furl
            Set m = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(furl)
            With Cells(I, 5)
                t = .Top
                l = .Left
                w = .Width
                h = .Height
            End With
            With m
                .Top = t
                .Left = l
                .ShapeRange.Width = w
                .ShapeRange.Height = h
            End With
            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I'm not sure what your code was doing, but it appeared to be looking for perhaps an old style URL make-up that Google no longer use. Note: the code above works today, but Google can change the way their search engine builds its pages at any time.

Comment: Truly amazing work, ive been trying to sort this out on a daily basis for months.